# react-testing-library react test component update

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

New to react. what is the right approach to test the component value update which is depending on the action in other component?
Using `jest` + `react-testing-library`.

Imagine there is just 2 components(siblings) and a value updated through global state.

Here is the test:

```
it('updates default value on for submit click', async () => {
    const username = 'hello';

    const {getByTestId, container, rerender} = render(<App/>);

    //subscribe to DOM changes
    await waitForDomChange({container}).then(() => {
        const defaultUsername = getByTestId("username-value");
        expect(defaultUsername).toHaveTextContent(username);
    });

    //set username
    const usernameInput = getByTestId("username-input");
    usernameInput.value = username;
    expect(usernameInput.value).toBe(username);

    const submitBtn = getByTestId("btn-submit");
    // console.log(prettyDOM(submitBtn));
    fireEvent.click(submitBtn, {button: 0});
});
```

The form is in one component and the value is shown in another. They're rendered simultaneously. In this test, value in the second component never gets updated.
What is the right approach to test it? If it is correct approach - what is possibly goes wrong?

Comment: How do you check the results of a click? *value in the second component never gets updated* - what's first and what's second? It's unknown what may go wrong. Please, provide all relevant code. This includes App at least.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but it looks like your issue is here:

```
usernameInput.value = username;
```

Rather than setting the value property by hand, you should use the `fireEvent` method to change the value:

```
fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: username } });
```